# CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage - pixelFormat

Tags: ios, textures, metal

From the tests I did, the pixelFormat parameter of CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage is the pixel format of the metal texture and not the actual pixel format of data in the Cove Video buffer. Is this right?

In that case, where and when the conversion is done (if the texture and buffer formats are different)? Is there any performance penallity for that conversion?

EDIT:

I rechecked documentation and the pixelFormat parameter is described as follow: "The Metal pixel format constant describing the image buffer’s "data. So the pixelFormat should match the pixel format of the Core Video buffer data, no?

However, for the same Core Video buffer (whichcontains integer data), it works if I use either MTLPixelFormatR8Uint or MTLPixelFormatR8Unorm. The only difference is that the values received in my shader are either integers [0..255] or floats [0.0..1.0]. In the later case, I would have expected to receive garbage since the intergers is the buffer would have been interpreted as floats. No?

Comment: `MTLPixelFormatR8Unorm` interprets the data as unsigned integers and then *converts* them to floats in the range [0.0..1.0]. It does not expect the data to already be some 8-bit floating-point type.

Comment: So pixelFormat is not the format of the Core Video buffer data as described by the documentation, right? Also, Is there any performance penalty for that conversion? From what I recall, conversion from integer to float are free when done in the shader.

Comment: It is the format of the Core Video buffer data. What did I say that implied otherwise? Both `MTLPixelFormatR8Uint` and `MTLPixelFormatR8Unorm` say that the buffer data consists of 8-bit unsigned integers in the range from [0..255]. It's just that, in shaders, unsigned normalized values are presented as floating-point values. That doesn't affect what's in the buffer data. I don't know for sure about a performance penalty, but 8-bit `Unorm` formats are very common for rendering, so they're presumably plenty fast.

Comment: If the difference between MTLPixelFormatR8Uint and MTLPixelFormatR8Unorm is not the buffer data type (both say that the buffer data consists of 8-bit unsigned integers in the range from [0..255]) but rather how the MTLTexture outputs its values, isn't correct to says that the pixelFormat parameter describe the pixel format (or the output) of the MTLTexture?

Comment: Ok, I think I got it... both those format doesn't says how The MTLTexture should output its values but they rather says how the 8-bit interger values in the buffer should be interpreted (i.e. their format).. For Uint, it mean that 255 is 255 and for Unorm, 255 mean max range and thus 1.0. I got it?

Comment: I would say the pixel format specifies both the buffer data format and the resulting Metal texture format. It's basically the same as how `-[MTLTexture replaceRegion:...]` works, in that the pixel format specifies the format of the texture but also implies the format of the data buffer you supply so the data is interpreted properly. Both of the two formats we're discussing have the same implication for the data buffer format. In that sense, they're interchangeable. Which you choose is how you want Metal to interpret the texture elsewhere.

Comment: On a mildly related note, I'm trying to find documentation on how quickly one can safely release the underlying CVPixelBuffer once one has created a MTLTexture.  After the CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage call?  After the CVMetalTextureGetTexture call?  These are CVPixelBuffers provided by AVFoundation (I believe they're on the GPU).

Comment: Don't worry about when to decrement the ref count of the pixel buffers, just it when you are done using the pixel buffer. The metal texture cache also holds a ref to the pixel buffer so you are not actually deallocating the pixel buffer (they will just be returned to a pool anyway). A metal texture is just a collection of bits that describe how to interpret the data in the core video pixel buffer.